# How to call a function of component from outside in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

How to invoke a function of an Angular Component from parant component. What I am trying to achieve here is to get a confirmation message before closing the modal in the  parant component.

The function inside the child component will check for unsaved changes. And if there are any unsaved changes, child will call then another modal for confirmation.

Upon confirmation from this internal modal, I will then call back again the modal in the parant to invoke a `this.autoPopupUnratedModal.dismiss()` call

This is kinda coupled with mess but I am not able to find a clear solution.
Although there are many answeres to this question, nothing seems to solve my problem. Maybe I am look at the wrong sources.

```html
<modal #autoPopupUnratedModal size="lg" [keyboard]="'false'" [backdrop]="'static'">
    <modal-header [show-close]="true">
        <h2 class="modal-title">List of unrated jobs</h2>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>

        <unrated-job-notification #unratedNofitication
                 [(onDiscard)]="isCloseNotification"
                 (onDiscard)="onCloseConfirmation($event)">
        </unrated-job-notification>

    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="false">
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="rateAnotherTime()">
           Rate another time
        </button>
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

Comment: The implementation seems messy for sure !  The answer provided by @Debojyoti will surely would but I think you should focus more on creating better relationship among components

Comment: From your question, I can guess that you have one `ParentComponent` (P1) and 2 `ChildComponents` which are sibling to each other. is it ?

Comment: Yes, My parent itself is a modal, and that modal will call another modal dialog as a confirmation: yes: no option. upon confirming yes, the parent modal's host which is just a component has to perform some task.

Answer (score 0):

To call a child's function from it's parent, you can use viewchild to get it's reference or a service with of rxjs observable implementation.

Using viewchild will suit your problem
Here is a sample child and parent component where the parent is calling `foo()` method of it's child component

### Child component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor() { }

  foo() {
    // I will be called from my parent
  }

}
```

### Parent component

```
<app-child #child_comp></app-child>




import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('child_comp') childComp;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.childComp.foo();
  }

}
```